I get this error related to app gallery I am making
/C:/Users/m3ada/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/screenshot-2.3.0/lib/screenshot.dart:164:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'size'.

        size: logicalSize,

        ^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:28:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.

  const ViewConfiguration({

        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/m3ada/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_colorpicker-1.0.3/lib/src/colorpicker.dart:659:53: Error: The getter 'bodyText1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyText1'.

                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,

                                                    ^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/m3ada/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_colorpicker-1.0.3/lib/src/colorpicker.dart:669:53: Error: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyText2'.

                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,

                                                    ^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/m3ada/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_colorpicker-1.0.3/lib/src/palette.dart:951:55: Error: The getter 'bodyText1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyText1'.

                          Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,

                                                      ^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/m3ada/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_colorpicker-1.0.3/lib/src/palette.dart:960:57: Error: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyText2'.

                            Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,

                                                        ^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/m3ada/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_colorpicker-1.0.3/lib/src/palette.dart:1042:58: Error: The getter 'bodyText1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyText1'.

          Text('Hex', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),

                                                         ^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/m3ada/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_colorpicker-1.0.3/lib/src/palette.dart:1045:47: Error: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyText2'.

          width: (Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.fontSize ?? 14) * 10,

                                              ^^^^^^^^^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 40s

Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have never used that package screenshot directly
but it is being used by another package

could you add view.dart ? the error related to something int that file.


flutter clean

flutter pub get


It will work fine.

no it is not working i tried several times

what is your flutter version?

Flutter 3.22.0-0.1.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 29babcb32a (5 days ago) • 2024-04-03 17:17:04 -0500
Engine • revision 97550907b7
Tools • Dart 3.4.0 (build 3.4.0-282.1.beta) • DevTools 2.34.2

Create a blank project and  test the package again.

I did same error
